# a word for 'a firm conviction about existence following death, pragmatically keeping one from excessive this-worldliness, materialism, etc'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Provided it is clear enough, the title speaks for itself, I guess.To clarify though, I'm after a word or phrase, with **positive** connotation, that may denote:

- *a strong personal ideology or belief, inspiring the believer to think of life and its vicissitudes with reference to afterdeath and humankind's immortality, resulting in their taking worldly matters lightly, tolerate difficulties easily, etc.*

It may be a synonym for a word in my native language whose exact translation could be *death-mindedness*, to my knowledge. Besides, it is not associated with any specific **religious** inclination, at all.

any suggestions?

Comment: I'd be grateful also if someone edits my question; I'd love to learn how to put it in a more natural way. Thanks.

Comment: You want an antonym for 'worldly'?

Comment: Maybe 'Reincarnation': the belief that the soul, upon death of the body, comes back to earth in another body or form.

Comment: Having [inner peace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_peace)? [Asceticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asceticism)? [Gelassenheit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnung#Gelassenheit)? [Unworldly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unworldly)? [Otherworldly](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=otherworldly)? Having a spiritual outlook on life?

Comment: @Josh61; @ A E ; I understand reincarnation to be a different concept, i'm afraid. The word I'm after involves a deep-rooted _there-exists-an-afterlife_ belief, that orients, shapes, guides, etc. the believer's conduct in life. It *causes* inner peace and *brings* asceticism, yeah

Comment: I think an 'enlightened' person may hold the beliefs you describe? It is a term used in Buddhism, however

Comment: I would probably say they were 'taking a philosophical view of life's troubles, content in the assurance they felt of rewards in the hereafter'.

Comment: The element of your question that needs further clarification is  "*pragmatically* keeping one from excessive this-worldliness, materialism, etc.'.  Please elaborate on what you mean by 'pragmatically'? Fear of eternal damnation? Fear of being reincarnated as a lesser life form? I think we need to know the basis of the pragmatism.

Comment: @TRomano;By *Pragmatically*, I mean that such belief is strong enough to find a *practical* expression in every context of the believer's life. The word for such person in my language is margandish :marg (death)+andish (reflector/one that incessantly considers). A *margandish* person incessantly considers death/hereafter/immortality, in each and every move in their life, as an unescapable fact. This outlook, in turn, amounts to a practical point where worldly concerns, objectives and pursuits (material wealth, fame, maximization of one's benefit, etc) dwarf beside the concept of immorality.

Comment: @WS2 ;Yes, your description comes close, except for *reward*, though. is there a specific word/phrase for this description?

Comment: During the European middle ages, this outlook was summed up by the Latin phrase *memento mori*, i.e. remember death.

Comment: EXACTLY:
<that memento mori which it never ceases to din into the ears of the faithful — Paul Siwek> MW Unabridged - Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***immortalism.*** In philosophy and religion, it is the belief in soul's immortality rather than biological immortality.

> Immortalists believe that at the core of every human is an immortal soul, a spiritual entity, “a transcendental ego,” which has existed forever, will exist forever, and separates from the body at death.
>
> <sub>[Philosophy of Religion: The Basics by Richard E. Creel]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would call it simply *faith*

i.e. a firm belief in something for which there is no proof, (or no prove is needed.)

edit:

Actually, coming to think of it, *faith* sounds too religious for the context.

Perhaps some of these are a bit closer;

**insouciant**
inˈso͞osēənt,ˌaNso͞oˈsyäNt/

adjective

  showing a casual lack of concern; indifferent.

**centered**

  (of a person) well balanced and confident (or serene)

**happy-go-lucky**

adjective

  cheerfully unconcerned about the future

**unflustered**
ənˈfləstərd/

adjective

  not agitated; calm and self-controlled.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, but I guess they are not doing full justice to the concept I'm looking for.It could be on my part, cause of my failing English though (or maybe a deep cultural chasm is involved.)